# MySQL Complicated SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (`tbl_filters`) with 3 columns: `id`, `cat`, `val`

`id` & `val` are numeric, `cat` is varchar. There are multiple rows for each id.

I also have another table (`tbl_info`) with multiple columns, including an `id` which corresponds to the `id` from `tbl_filters`. There is a column called `name`, which is what I'm looking for.

I would like to select the name of all the rows which match a set value for `cat`, but only if the `val` for `cat` is the maximum for this id, and only if it is above a minimum set `val`.

In pseudocode it would be something like:

```
SELECT tbl_info.name FROM tbl_info,tbl_filters
WHERE (tbl_info.id=tbl_filters.id) AND (cat="mycat") AND (val>=0.3)
AND (there are no other rows for this id in tbl_info with a higher value for val)
```

Example:

```
tbl_filters
id,cat,val
1 eg1 0.43
1 eg2 0.60
1 eg3 0.78

tbl_info
id name
1 MyName
```

In the above example, a value should only be returned if I am looking for the `cat` called eg3, since that has the highest value. For the other cats, nothing should be returned, since they are not the highest value.

Another option would be to make a column in `tbl_info` just for the cat with the highest value, but that is a messy solution I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Check the HAVING documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html
It willl allow you to compare against the max of the column inside a group

Comment: 1) Can a cat have many values? 2) You said "since that has the highest value", you meant the highest value for id=1 or the highest value of all cats of all ID (which is to say the highest value of the column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I THINK I'm following you...  The INNER-MOST query pre-qualifies the HIGHEST Value per ID of your minimum value qualification, and the category that qualifies.  ONCE you get that list, re-join back to get the name from the tbl_info.  I've re-joined to the tbl_filters a second time in case there were other elements on that record you want, such as the date of the rate, or other things.  If you DONT need that, you can ignore the second "tf2" join and just change the fields list from tf2.val to PreQualified.HighestQualVal.

```
select
      ti.id,
      ti.name,
      tf2.val
   from
      ( select 
              tf.id,
              max( tf.val ) as HighestQualVal
           from
              tbl_filters tf
           where
                  tf.cat = "mycat"
              and tf.val >= 0.3
      ) PreQualified

      JOIN tbl_info ti
         on PreQualified.id = ti.id

      JOIN tbl_filters tf2
         on PreQualified.id = tf2.id
         AND PreQualified.HighestQualVal = tf2.val
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
select ti.name, MaxId.maxVal from
    (select tf1.id, tf1.cat, max(tf1.val) as maxVal from tbl_filters1 tf1
    where tf1.cat = 'eg3' and tf1.val >= 0.0
    group by tf1.id, tf1.cat) MaxCat
inner join (
    select tf2.id, max(tf2.val) as maxVal from tbl_filters2 tf2
    group by tf2.id) MaxId
on (MaxCat.id = MaxId.id and MaxCat.maxVal = MaxId.maxVal)
inner join tbl_info ti on MaxId.id = ti.id
```

Example [here](http://sqlize.com/h9aXr6TCG7)

Basically, and if I'm not wrong (again), I'm getting all the maximum val per each id and cat pair. Then get the maximum val for each id. If both match, i.e. if the max for the cat is the same as the max for the whole id, then I return the results.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Limit 1 seems to be logically incorrect, because there could be multiple ids being reported on at once, yes?

Comment: Actually, my solution sucked in many aspects. I'm rewriting it again.